displaying a 3x3 grid in ultimate tic tac toe using C++
im trying to get my code to display as a 3x3 grid of tic tac toe games but it will only display in a single column i know there will be other issues with this code but only working on getting it to display properly atm thanks.
here is the code i have
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "TicTacToe.h"
int main() {
    NBTicTacToe game;
    game.displayBoards();
    return 0;
}

this is the main function and most of the code for this is at the bottom under NBTicTacToe
#ifndef TICTACTOE_H_
#define TICTACTOE_H_
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int BOARDSIZE = 3;
class TicTacToe {
private:
    int board[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];
    int noOfMoves;
public:
    TicTacToe();
    bool isValidMove(int, int);
    bool getXMove(int&, int&);
    bool getOMove(int&, int&);
    void addMove(int, int, int);
    int gameStatus();
    int play();
    void displayBoard();
};
class NBTicTacToe {
    private:
        TicTacToe boards[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];
        int currentBoardX;
        int currentBoardY;
    public:
        NBTicTacToe();
        void displayBoards();
        TicTacToe& getCurrentBoard();
        void setCurrentBoard(int, int);
        void playCurrentBoard();

};
TicTacToe::TicTacToe() {
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            board[row][col] = 0;
    noOfMoves = 0;
}
void TicTacToe::displayBoard() {
    cout << "   1    2    3" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++) {
        cout << i + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARDSIZE; j++) {
            char playerSymbol = ' ';
            if (board[i][j] == 1)
                playerSymbol = 'X';
            else if (board[i][j] == -1)
                playerSymbol = 'O';
            cout << setw(3) << playerSymbol;
            if (j != BOARDSIZE -1)
                cout << " |";
        }
        cout << endl;
        if (i != BOARDSIZE -1)
            cout << " ____|____|____" << endl << "     |    |    " << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
bool TicTacToe::isValidMove(int x, int y) {
    if (board[x][y] == 1 || board[x][y] == -1){
        cout << "Please enter a valid move: \n";
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
bool TicTacToe::getXMove(int &x, int &y) {
    if (noOfMoves >= BOARDSIZE * BOARDSIZE)
        return false;
    int row, col;
    do {
        row = rand() % BOARDSIZE;
        col = rand() % BOARDSIZE;
    } while (!isValidMove(row, col));
    x = row;
    y = col;
    return true;
}
bool TicTacToe::getOMove(int &x, int &y) {
    if (noOfMoves >= BOARDSIZE * BOARDSIZE)
        return false;
    int row, col;
    do {
        cin >> row >> col;
        cout << endl;
    } while (!isValidMove(row - 1, col - 1));
    x = row - 1;
    y = col - 1;
    return true;
}
void TicTacToe::addMove(int x, int y, int player) {
    board[x][y] = player;
}
int TicTacToe::gameStatus() {
//Check rows for a win
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
    if (board[i][0] == 1 && board[i][1] == 1 && board[i][2] == 1) {
        return 1;
    }else if (board[i][0] == -1 && board[i][1] == -1 && board[i][2] == -1){
        return -1;
    }
}
//Check columns for a win
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
    if (board[0][i] == 1 && board[1][i] == 1 && board[2][i] == 1) {
        return 1;
    }else if (board[0][i] == -1 && board[1][i] == -1 && board[2][i] == -1){
        return -1;
    }
}
//Check diagonals for a win
if (board[0][0] == 1 && board[1][1] == 1 && board[2][2] == 1) {
        return 1;
    }else if (board[0][2] == 1 && board[1][1] == 1 && board[2][0] == 1){
        return 1;
    }else if (board[0][0] == -1 && board[1][1] == -1 && board[2][2] == -1) {
        return -1;
    }else if (board[0][2] == -1 && board[1][1] == -1 && board[2][0] == -1){
        return -1;
    }
//check for Draw
bool draw = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == 0) {
            draw = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
    if (draw)
        return 2;
    return 0;
}
int TicTacToe::play() {
    int player = 1;
    displayBoard();
    int done = 0;
    while (done == 0) {
        int x, y;
        if (player == 1) {
            cout << "player X is moving: \n";
            getXMove(x, y);
        } else {
            cout << "please enter your move: ";
            getOMove(x, y);
        }
        addMove(x, y, player);
        noOfMoves++;
        displayBoard();
        done = gameStatus();
        if (done == 1) {
            cout << "Player X wins!" << endl;
            return 1;
        } else if (done == -1) {
            cout << "Player O wins!" << endl;
            return -1;
        } else if (done == 2) {
            cout << "Draw game!" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        if (player == 1)
            player = -1;
        else
            player = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
NBTicTacToe::NBTicTacToe() : currentBoardX(0), currentBoardY(0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < BOARDSIZE; j++) {
            boards[i][j] = TicTacToe();
        }
    }
}
void NBTicTacToe::displayBoards() {
    for (int r =0; r < BOARDSIZE; r++){// display rows
        for (int c =0; c < BOARDSIZE; c++){ 
            boards[r][c].displayBoard();
            if (c <BOARDSIZE) {
            cout << " - - - - - - - - \n" ;
            }
        }
        if (r < BOARDSIZE){
            for (int c = 0; c < BOARDSIZE; c++){
                if (c < BOARDSIZE) {
                    cout << " || ";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
TicTacToe& NBTicTacToe::getCurrentBoard() {
    return boards[currentBoardX][currentBoardY];
}
void NBTicTacToe::setCurrentBoard(int x, int y) {
    currentBoardX = x;
    currentBoardY = y;
}
void NBTicTacToe::playCurrentBoard() {
    getCurrentBoard().play();
}
#endif


should be getting something close to this:
ultimate tic tac toe

if you want to stick to using the standard library you can only output line by line, you'll need to output 3 boards at a time if you want to tile them. Alternatively libraries like ncurses or the windows console APIs will allow you to write to arbitrary locations on the console

It's impossible to do animation in the standard C++.
It is a "stream" which means it "throws" out characters and those characters are put one after the other onto the screen. An "enter" charcter - starts putting characters from a new line. There is no way to go back.
But specific enviroments have a way to do this.
What exactly do you want achieve?

You would need a library like ncurses, but I have the feeling that's a bit too much for your current project.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

A way that I would suggest is to work on strings.
Make the class TicTacToe have a function 'to_strings' which returns std::array or std::vector of std::strings.
Then in the the display_board function, you can get the first 3 TicTacToe boards and then display the first lines ended with an enter.
Then the next 3 boards, and so on.
for example:
void display_boards()
{
    for (auto& boards_row : boards)
    {
        auto board1 = boards_row[0].to_strings();
        auto board2 = boards_row[1].to_strings();
        auto board3 = boards_row[2].to_strings();

        for (int line_idx = 0; line_idx < board1.size(); ++line_idx)
        {
            std::cout << board1[line_idx] << board2[line_idx] << board3[line_idx] << '\n';
        }
    }
}

